# MS Access: Missing or broken reference to excel.exe 1.8

Tags: excel, vba

I have a access front end tool that works fine on other system. When I try to run it on my Win 7 system(with word, excel but not access 2010) it gives me the error "Missing or broken reference to excel.exe 1.8". I am using MS access runtime 2013(have also tried runtime 2010, 2007). I do not have permission to install access on my system so cannot change to late binding. I opened MS Excel > Developer > Visual Basic > Tools > References but there are no Missing references listed there.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I am on a tight deadline to migrate the front end to web so any prompt help would save my neck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution... I think
I had the same issue. I believe it was caused by someone doing an edit using a newer version of Access. 
Access RTE is of difference version that the Office installation, so the edit added (this is my assumption) a reference to EXCEL.exe at the location of the newest office folder. 
My solution was to uncheck the reference, knowing that it is not used in our application. If you need excel, you should add the reference to your actual excel installation folder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no solution other than implementing latebinding by installing access instead of access runtime. Now I was able to fix the problem.